# Why do I have the perform the npm install multiple times for the ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template for Visual Studio

Tags: angular, npm, asp.net-core, webpack

I am working with the ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template for Visual Studio provided in the Blog from Steve Sanderson (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/). Unfortunately, most of the times I have to run `npm install` and `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` more than once to get it starting if the node modules are not downloaded yet.

How can I avoid that, so that running `npm install` and `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` has to be run only once?